# Does this diagram have redundancy?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, erd

I have question about data redundancy.

I have following diagram:
[image]

Packages are stored in Warehouses. A package can be moved from one warehouse to another. I want to store information about where a package was on certain date (in which warehouse) and information about transports between warehouses.
Transport departs from one warehouse with multiple packages and arrives at different warehouse.
Package can be in certain warehouse only once (if it is transported to another warehouse, it cannot, at any time, go back to previous warehouse.)

I came up with this:

[image]

Is this second diagram correct or is there redundancy?

### Edit:

I changed *Deliveries* to *Packages* as my intention was that Delivery is one undividable thing (like a box or letter) - sorry for confusion, it was a bad name. 
So based on @philipxy answer, I think this diagram is better for what I want to achieve. I removed *DateStorage*, and add **inital warehouse** property to *Packages*.

[image]

Comment: According to the structure of "DateStorage", a delivery can be stored in any particular warehouse only once. According to "Transports", a delivery can be transported only once. Seems odd to me. Is that what you intended? (Functional dependencies are probably a better starting point.

Comment: *"Date attribute in DateStorage is date on which delivery was put to that Warehouse."* Then what's the difference between "DateStorage" and "Transports"? Presumably, a delivery gets "date storaged" by being transported to a warehouse.

Comment: You seem to be using "delivery" in two different ways: some stuff, and a part of that stuff initially stored at a particular warehouse (on one date per initial storage.) Then a part (each identifiable by an initial storage delivery-warehouse pair) might have been transported from where it was to a different warehouse any number of times (possibly on the same date)? Can a delivery then have two parts in the same warehouse?

Comment: PS But then you say "Warehouse in which the delivery is, can be found by checking which date in DateStorage is the latest". So storage records where a part has been over time, and date is part of the key?

Comment: It is not clear what are the *predicates* in your post-edit design. *Predicates precede everything; a database cannot be filled or interpreted without them.* I don't know what modeling/diagramming method you are trying to use. Is this 4 entities? What does a named line indicate? Are Contains, From, To & Delivers relationships/associations? With what attributes? Are they FKs? In what predicates/tables? Beware that adding an id does not make constraints go away, but complicates them, and is only *necessary* if you can't distinguish between application things via other attributes. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using "delivery" in two different ways: some stuff, and a part of that stuff initially (or most recently?) stored at a particular warehouse (associated with just one date?). Then a part (each identifiable by an initial storage delivery-warehouse pair?) might have been transported from where it was to a different warehouse any number of times. Can a delivery then have two parts in the same warehouse after transpord? Can a part be transported twice on the same day? Can a transport be to the same warehouse?

Your question's characterization of your application's tables/relationships and constraints is unclear; but it seems you might need an answer that suggests how you can proceed before it can become clear.

You seem to be interested in something like the following. (I don't claim it's consistent with everything in your question; but neither is everything in your question.) Using ER, for every base entity type & relationship type of interest we give a *predicate* determining its table's rows--a fill-in-the-blanks sentence template parameterized by column names.

```
-- DID ids a delivery
Delivery(did)

-- WID ids a warehouse
Warehouse(wid)

-- a delivery DID part was initially stored at warehouse WID on date D
storage(did,wid,d)
    key {did, wid}
    FK (did) to delivery, (wid) to warehouse

-- part DID-WID was transported from warehouse FID to warehouse TID on date D
Transport(did, wid, fid, tid, d)
    key {did, wid, fid, d}, {did, wid, tid, d}
    FK (did, wid) to storage, (fid) & (tid) to warehouse
```

This may or may not capture state and constraints of your application situations.

However, supposing this is consistent with your application, it isn't necessarily part of the design you want. (Although you might be able to express the design you want in terms of it.)

Eg If a part can be transported only once per date then you don't need date d in the Transport keys. Eg You could drop fid from Transport, because you could reconstruct it from its did & its chain of transports. Eg If you only care about where parts are now, you don't want this Storage. Eg You may want initial storage, transports, and where a part is now (essenially, a part entity table), even though you can derive the latter from the former.

Eg If a delivery can only have one part per warehouse then you can also identify a part by its current warehouse, so you could have:

```
-- same predicate as Transport
-- part DID-WID was transported from warehouse FID to warehouse TID on date D
Transport2(did, fid, tid, d)
    key {did, fid, d}, {did, tid, d}
    FK (did) to delivery, (fid) & (tid) to warehouse
```

In either design a part's delivery plus the warehouse at the start of the chain of its transports must form a pair in storage.